# Motion layout. OnSwipe doesn't handle correctly drag event. What is the root problem?

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

So, I have simple scene:

```
 <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/motion_01_cl_start"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/motion_01_cl_end"
        motion:duration="300">

    <OnSwipe
        motion:touchRegionId="@id/imageView"
        motion:dragDirection="dragUp"/>
</Transition>


<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/motion_01_cl_start">
    <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/testView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"

            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:elevation="3dp"/>

    <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"

            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:elevation="4dp"/>

</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/motion_01_cl_end">
    <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/testView"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    />

    <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="290dp"
            android:elevation="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    />
</ConstraintSet>
```

As you may see, in Transition I have swipe handling with dragDirection "dragUp". But problem is that it works as dragDown, can't understand why. I tried to set dragDirection to dragDown, but it works as expected. Is there is any problems with direction handling?

Here is my layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/motionLayout">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id='@+id/testView'
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_width="300dp"/>


    <ImageView
           android:layout_width="300dp"
           android:layout_height="400dp"
           android:id="@+id/imageView"
           android:src="@drawable/img"
           android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Do you now why I may have this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why onSwipe does not handle correct drag event?

The drag direction is decided by the `MotionLayout` rendering engine itself based on the placement of the `touchAnchorId`.

To work around this, add a dummy view as the `touchAnchorId` and add sliding animation for that view in the required direction. Since we don't need to make this dummy view visible on the UI, we can use the '[Space](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space)' view provided by the android SDK as the dummy view.

```
 <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**Add ConstraintLayout dependency into your build.gradle file**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
}
```

So, your layout and motion resource files will look like given below

*activity_main.xml*

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/motionLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    motion:layoutDescription="@xml/motionscene">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id='@+id/testView'
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_width="300dp"/>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/abd"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

*motionscene.xml*

```
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/motion_01_cl_start"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/motion_01_cl_end"
        motion:duration="300">

        <OnSwipe
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/space"
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"/>
    </Transition>


    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/motion_01_cl_start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/testView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"

            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:elevation="3dp"/>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"

            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:elevation="4dp"/>
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/space"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/motion_01_cl_end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/testView"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="290dp"
            android:elevation="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/space"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            />
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

and the output will look like the below gif

[image: gif image showing sample animation]